# How to get the row number and column number of a particular table from excel sheet using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I want to automate one application , the data I am getting is from Excel which contains the data table .
I want to know from which row the table is starting in excel sheet and and on which row it ends.
I am using python and Plotly Dash , Upload component to get the excel sheet .

Ex : In this case how can I know that my table is starting from 65 ?
[image]

Comment: before row 63 is there something ? or just blank ?

Comment: @DataSciRookie before row 63 there is meta information about the report

Comment: One option is to read it as individual cells and then reshape. [xlsx_cells](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/#janitor.io.xlsx_cells) can do this. You can identify the row that has bold font and pick only rows from there downward

Comment: try to add header in your read_excel :  pd.read_excel( header=62 or maybe 63)

Comment: @DataSciRookie The row no. is not fixed , the table can start from row 15 , 42 or 63 etc .

Comment: do you always have the same header ?

Comment: @DataSciRookie The header for table is same but the row from which the table header is starting is different

Comment: yeah but let's say you already know the header, so it means that you can read the file from the beginning, looking for the header in the raw with the dataframe (which is dirty). When you found the header it means that you find the index row to parse for the header in pd.read_excel, no ?

Comment: Ok you mean to say like read the excel file , in that raw file , figure out the line from where the header for the table is starting ,take that row number  and pass it to pd.read_excel  ? am I correct ?